# Inverse Bessel Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Is there any reference on this process? For example, analytical derivations for the hitting times, density, etc?

Im studying local martingales and am interested in the density of hitting times for the Inverse Bessel process

Comment: A start would be to look at recent things by Protter and/or Föllmer and/or Yor.

Comment: Thats what Im studying actually. But they all keep saying everything is known. Im curious where it's known from.

Comment: "But they all keep saying everything is known." Certainly not (at least, not everywhere). Yor, for instance, was known for having no reluctance whatsoever to go back to basics.

Comment: Revuz Yor then? I looked at the citations and they all point there. Ill have a look and update.

Comment: Anyway, I guess it suffices to look at the bessel itself and the inverse would be around soemthing like that